# store ID's in the database

Tags: c#, sql

i have a slight problem here,I have the following master tables

M_employee

```
EMPID    Name

1      abc
2      xyz
```

M_Division

```
DIVID  EMPID  DIVISON

1        2      arts
2        1      science
```

M_Designation

```
DESGID  EMPID  Designation

1         2      Teacher
2         1      Scientist
```

and based on the ID's present in the master table i retrieve few fields on a label in a form....What i want to do is when i store these values of the form in a new table i want only the id's to be stored and not the text values which are being displayed in the label of the form.Below is the code I tried..Can anyone help me?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Xml.Linq;
namespace Travel1.Forms
{
    public partial class temporaryduty : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Server; Database; Integrated security = true");
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Lbltoday.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                GetName();//adding the group to the dropdownbox
            }
        }

        private void GetName()
        {
             SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select EMPID,Name FROM M_employee where IsActive=1 ORDER BY Name", conn);
             DataSet objDs = new DataSet();
             SqlDataAdapter sd = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
             conn.Open();
             sd.Fill(objDs);
             conn.Close();
             if (objDs.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
             {
                 ddlname.DataSource = objDs.Tables[0];
                 ddlname.DataTextField = "Name";
                 ddlname.DataValueField = "EMPID";
                 ddlname.DataBind();
                 ddlname.Items.Insert(0, "--Select--");
             }
         }

         protected void ddlname_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
             GetDivision(ddlname.SelectedItem.Value);
         }

         private void GetDivision(string Name)
         {
             SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT M_employee.Name, M_Division.DIVISION, M_Division.DIVID AS Expr1, M_Designation.DesigID AS Expr2, M_Designation.Designation FROM M_employee INNER JOIN M_Division ON M_employee.DIVID = M_Division.DIVID INNER JOIN M_Designation ON M_employee.DesigID = M_Designation.DesigID WHERE M_employee.EMPID=@EMPID ", conn);
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EMPID", Name);
             DataSet objDs = new DataSet();
             SqlDataAdapter sd = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
             conn.Open();
             sd.Fill(objDs);
             conn.Close();
             if (objDs.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
             {
                 lbldiv.Text = objDs.Tables[0].Rows[0]["DIVISION"].ToString();
                 lbldesig.Text = objDs.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Designation"].ToString();
             }
        }

        protected void btnSubmit_Click2(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string RelaseDate = Calendar1.SelectedDate.Date.ToString();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into T_TADA_tempform(EMPID,DIVID,DesigID) values(@EMPID,@DIVID,@DesigID)", conn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EMPID", ddlname.SelectedValue);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DIVID", lbldesig.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DesigID", lbldiv.Text);
            if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                conn.Open();
                int cnt = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();
                if (cnt == 1)
                {
                    Response.Redirect("form.aspx");
                }
                else
                    Response.Write("Form has not been submitted,Please Try again!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ad an aside, you have a lot of `IDisposable` resources here which should best be wrapped in `using` statements for proper deterministic disposal.

Comment: can u let me know more bout this?

Comment: I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: Not related to your question, but what is the purpose of the employee_id field in the m_division and m_designation tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you read in your division and designation, store the ids somewhere, like in a private filed of this class:

```
public partial class temporaryduty : System.Web.UI.Page
{
  private int divisionId;
  private int designationId;
```

...

```
if (objDs.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
{
  lbldiv.Text = objDs.Tables[0].Rows[0]["DIVISION"].ToString();
  lbldesig.Text = objDs.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Designation"].ToString();
  divisionId = objDs.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Expr1"];
  designationId = objDs.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Expr2"];
}
```

Then, on your button click use those fields to insert the ids:

```
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DIVID", divisionId);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DesigID", designationId);
```

Comment: oh okay...i will try that out josh...and let you know :)

Comment: Sounds good.  Feel free to mark this as the answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: divisionId = objDs.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Expr1"]; it gives an error saying cannot convert object into string ...

Comment: I'm not sure why it's saying you should convert the object to a string if you made divisionId an int.  You could try something like divisionId = Convert.ToInt32(objDs.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Expr1"]).  Or, if you made divisionId a string instead, you could use ToString() like you did for the other datatable reads.

Comment: okay i tried something like objDS.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Expr1"]=divisionID and it works...but ill try it ur way too...thanks so much for your help...I guess I can take it from here :)

Answer (score 1):

As requested, here is the idiomatic way of using `using` for `IDisposable` resources. Note, I've done nothing else with the code's logic but that, so pay attention to other answers :)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Xml.Linq;
namespace Travel1.Forms
{
    public partial class temporaryduty : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Lbltoday.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                GetName();//adding the group to the dropdownbox
            }
        }
     private void GetName()
     {
         using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Server; Database; Integrated security = true"))
         using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select EMPID,Name FROM M_employee where IsActive=1 ORDER BY Name", conn))
         using (DataSet objDs = new DataSet())
         using (SqlDataAdapter sd = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
         {
             conn.Open();
             sd.Fill(objDs);
             if (objDs.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
             {
                ddlname.DataSource = objDs.Tables[0];
                ddlname.DataTextField = "Name";
                ddlname.DataValueField = "EMPID";
                ddlname.DataBind();
                ddlname.Items.Insert(0, "--Select--");
             }
         }
     }
     protected void ddlname_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         GetDivision(ddlname.SelectedItem.Value);
     }
     private void GetDivision(string Name)
     {
         using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Server; Database; Integrated security = true"))
         using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT M_employee.Name, M_Division.DIVISION, M_Division.DIVID AS Expr1, M_Designation.DesigID AS Expr2, M_Designation.Designation FROM M_employee INNER JOIN M_Division ON M_employee.DIVID = M_Division.DIVID INNER JOIN M_Designation ON M_employee.DesigID = M_Designation.DesigID WHERE M_employee.EMPID=@EMPID ", conn))
         using (DataSet objDs = new DataSet())
         using (SqlDataAdapter sd = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
         {
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EMPID", Name);
             conn.Open();
             sd.Fill(objDs);
             if (objDs.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
             {
                 lbldiv.Text = objDs.Tables[0].Rows[0]["DIVISION"].ToString();
                 lbldesig.Text = objDs.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Designation"].ToString();
             }
         }
     }
    protected void btnSubmit_Click2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string RelaseDate = Calendar1.SelectedDate.Date.ToString();
        int cnt;
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Server; Database; Integrated security = true"))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into T_TADA_tempform(EMPID,DIVID,DesigID) values(@EMPID,@DIVID,@DesigID)", conn))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EMPID", ddlname.SelectedValue);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DIVID", lbldesig.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DesigID", lbldiv.Text);
            conn.Open();
            cnt = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        if (cnt == 1)
            {
                Response.Redirect("form.aspx");
            }
            else
                Response.Write("Form has not been submitted,Please Try again!");
        }
    }
    }
```